# Understand the evaluation of the recursion (haskell)

Tags: haskell, recursion, evaluation

I have following code:

```
foo x y z
 | null x = y
 | null z = y
 | otherwise = foo (tail x) ([head x] ++ y ++ [head z]) (tail z)
```

and following inputs:

1. `[1] [2] [3]`
2. `[1,3,4] [2] [3,4]`
3. `[1,0] [2] [3,4]`

Evaluation for case 1:

```
otherwise: foo [] [1,2,3] []
null x = [1,2,3]
null z = [1,2,3]
```

Output: [1,2,3]

Evaluation for case 2:

```
otherwise: foo [3,4] [1,2,3] [4]
           foo [4] [3,2,4] []
null z = [3,2,4]
```

Output: [3,1,2,3,4]

Evaluation for case 3:

```
otherwise: foo [0] [1,2,3] [4]
           foo [] [0,2,4] []
null x = [0,2,4]
null z = [0,2,4]
```

Output: [0,1,2,3,4]

I don't understand how the recursion is composed after the last step

Comment: Can you say in words what one of the code blocks in "evaluation for case X" means? I can't make heads or tails of what you think is going on.

Comment: guarding for `null xs` is an anti-pattern. better write several equations, each with its patterns, like `foo [] y z = ...` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the code in your question, probably there's a typo: in case 2, nor `x` or `z` are `null`, therefore you go in the `otherwise`, as you write, but that means you call `foo` on `[2,3]`, not `[3,4]`, and `[1,2,3]` and `[4]`. Please, review your question.

Going to your *I don't understand how the recursion is composed after the last step*, the thing is simple: your function is chopping elements off `x` and `z` (simultaneously, as in the same level of recursion) as long as there are one or more on each of them, while making `y` grow. Then, as soon as `x` or `z` (or both) become `null`, you'll exit the recursion by returning `y`.

Comment: I corrected the typo. I don't understand the output of case 2 and 3. Why is the output for case 2 `3,1,2,3,4`?

Comment: @MaxMustermann, if you go with pencil and paper, you'll find out, believe me. `otherwise` removes the head from the 1st and 3rd argument, and puts them around the 2nd argument. Try that on paper, and you'll see why the result is what it is. This is independent form Will Ness' suggestion, which you should follow nonetheless because he's right.